# Is there a crystal structure of ammonia in ionic form?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry, pnictogen

Like solid $\ce{PCl5}$, does solid $\ce{NH3}$ exist as $\ce{[NH4+][NH2-]}$ (i.e. ammonium amide)?

Comment: Now that's a different question, with an answer _"normally no, but..."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the work of Ninet et al. published in 2014 [[1](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.89.174103)], ammonia has a β-phase at 150 GPa, where it transitions into ionic crystalline form, forming $\ce{[NH4+][NH2-]}.$

#### References

1. Ninet, S.; Datchi, F.; Dumas, P.; Mezouar, M.; Garbarino, G.; Mafety, A.; Pickard, C. J.; Needs, R. J.; Saitta, A. M. Experimental and Theoretical Evidence for an Ionic Crystal of Ammonia at High Pressure. *Phys. Rev. B* **2014**, 89 (17), 174103. DOI: [10.1103/PhysRevB.89.174103](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.89.174103).